# Identifying questions in exam (text recognition)

Tags: machine-learning, text-mining, image-recognition, text-recognition

I have thousands of exams in pdf, which I'd like to extract it's questions into a standard format (JSON, YML or XML).

They are multiple choice:

> Question 1
>
> Who was the first man to walk on the moon?
>
> a) Yuri Gagarin
>
> b) Ellen Ripley
>
> c) Neil Armstrong
>
> d) Shepard
>
> Question 2
>
> How many planets are in the solar system ?
>
> a) 10
>
> b) 12
>
> c) 14
>
> d) 15
>
> (...)

In JSON:

```
{
  "number": 1,
  "wording": "Who as the first man to walk on the moon",
  "alternatives": {
    "a": Yuri Gagarin
    "b": Ellen Ripley
    "c": Neil Armstrong
    "d": Shepard
  }
}
```

The caveat is that as those exams were made by different teachers, so, they may differ slightly. That means that even extracting to plain text, I will not be able to match using regular expressions. (I've tried and the combinations (wording structure / alternative structure) are huge)

For example:

> "Question X (...)".
>
> "Question (X) (...)".
>
> "Question X - (...)".
>
> "X) (...)".
>
> "X- (...)".

The alternatives also might change:

> a) (...)
>
> a. (...)
>
> a- (...)
>
> 1) (...)

I guess I need some sort of machine learning tool in order to "teach" the program what is a question and make it find.

As an alternative, as the questions (in print) are physically distant one from another, I thought I could transform those PDFs into images and use some sort of image-recognition.

Is it feasible? Is there a tool (package, library, algorithm) for identifying those questions?

Answer (score 0):

There is no straight forward machine learning solution to your problem. If your PDFs are in 1000, and the formats are in 10s, better you write a string parser for each format. If you take the path of machine learning, the time to find solution may be longer. Python should help.

Comment: It is actually 100 thousands. But I guess you are right. I'll try a semi-automatic approach. Parse but also verify and correct manually.